# Roblox error - Attempt to index nil with 'EquipTool'

Tags: lua, roblox

I am coding a custom inventory, and when I try to equip the tool I get an error saying attempt to index nil with "EquipTool". The way it works is there is a value in each hotbar slot saying what is in the slot, and in the player there is a folder saying what is in the inventory.

```
local starterGui = game.StarterGui
local uis = game.UserInputService

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local humanoid = player.Character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid")
local playerGui = player.PlayerGui

local hotbar = playerGui.Inventory.Hotbar
local inventoryFrame = playerGui.Inventory.Inventory
local inventoryFolder = player.InventoryFolder

local keyConversions = {
    [Enum.KeyCode.One] = 1,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Two] = 2,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Three] = 3,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Four] = 4,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Five] = 5,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Six] = 6,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Seven] = 7,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Eight] = 8,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Nine] = 9,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Zero] = 10,
}

local function fillInventoryFolder()
    for i, v in pairs(player.Backpack:GetChildren()) do
        v.Parent = inventoryFolder
    end
end

local function updateHotbar()
    local maxSlots = 11
    local slot = 1
    for i, v in pairs(inventoryFolder:GetChildren()) do
        if slot < maxSlots then
            if hotbar[slot].SlotItem.Value == nil then
                hotbar[slot].SlotItem.Value = v
                hotbar[slot].Image = game.ReplicatedStorage.HotbarImages[tostring(hotbar[slot].SlotItem.Value)].Texture
                slot += 1
            end
        end
    end
end

local function equip(slot)
    local convertedSlot = keyConversions[slot]
    if inventoryFolder:FindFirstChild(tostring(hotbar[convertedSlot].SlotItem.Value)) then
        inventoryFolder:FindFirstChild(tostring(hotbar[convertedSlot].SlotItem.Value)).Parent = player.Backpack
        humanoid:EquipTool(player.Backpack[tostring(hotbar[convertedSlot].SlotItem.Value)])
    end
end

fillInventoryFolder()

uis.InputBegan:Connect(function(key, processed)
    if key.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.Keyboard then
        equip(key.KeyCode)
    end
end)

while wait() do
    updateHotbar()
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `humanoid` is `nil`. You probably need to add some `Wait`s as shown in the [docs](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Instance#FindFirstChildOfClass).

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local player = Players.LocalPlayer
local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()

local humanoid

while not humanoid do
    humanoid = character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid")
    if not humanoid then
        character.ChildAdded:Wait()
    end
end
```